# Backbone collection.fetch() causing TypeError: this.model is undefined

Tags: backbone.js

everything seems correct, but whenever I do the following, I get TypeError: f is undefined in backbone 1.1.2, Also, when I debug, I saw that it was able to receive the correct response, yet when I do categories.toJSON() I get nothing:

```
var categories = new App.Lookup.CategoryCollection();
categories.url = 'index.php?r=lookupapi/categories';
categories.fetch();

App.Lookup.CategoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Lookup.CategoryModel                
});

App.Lookup.CategoryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

I use the development version as suggested by user972 and got the following error message:

TypeError: this.model is undefined

categories.fetch() is the one causing the error, it pointed to this function in backbone:

```
 // Define how to uniquely identify models in the collection.
    modelId: function (attrs) {
      return attrs[this.model.prototype.idAttribute || 'id'];
    },
```

But I still couldn't figure out why it is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, have you referenced the script files in the proper order? It seems more of from script loading error than the code based.

```
<script src="underscore-1.6.0-min.js"></script>
<script src="backbone-1.1.2-min.js"></script>
```

Other thing that might be of help is to use non-min version of backbone and try locating where it is crashing and why?

```
 <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes it is: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendors/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendors/backbone-min.js"></script>

Comment: Please try using the non-min version and put breakpoint where it is crashing to see what values are being passed to which function?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `App.Lookup.CategoryModel` is not hoisted above `App.Lookup.CategoryCollection`. You need to define `App.Lookup.CategoryModel` before you use it.

So change your code to:

```
App.Lookup.CategoryModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

App.Lookup.CategoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: App.Lookup.CategoryModel                
});

var categories = new App.Lookup.CategoryCollection();
categories.url = 'index.php?r=lookupapi/categories';
categories.fetch();
```

In response to:

```
I saw that it was able to receive the correct response, yet when I do      
categories.toJSON() I get nothing
```

If you want to see the results of `fetch` you need to pass a `success` callback:

```
categories.fetch({
   success: function(collection, response, options) {
      console.log(collection.toJSON());
   }
});
```

Comment: I was having the same problem. In my case, I had completely omitted the Backbone.Model definition; fixed by adding it at the right spot. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.